# VLOOKUP keeps giving #N/A

Tags: excel-2010

I am using VLOOKUP to do some looking up and I have all the values right but it keeps giving me #N/A. Here is what I am doing:

I have a data in 2 columns, Column A has names and column B has ID. I have copy and pasted the some details further down the columns and that is what I am searching. It keeps giving me #N/A when the data it is search is the same data I pasted.
The formula I am using is as follows:
`VLOOKUP(B10,A30:B46,1,FALSE)`

Any ideas why this is doing it?

When I use TRUE instead it gives me a really wrong match. nowhere close

Comment: you could also use the `IFERROR()` function to keep using the vlookup  https://exceljet.net/formula/vlookup-without-na-error

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 The thing with IFERROR is that won't give me the correct result just inform me of the error. Using INDEX MATCH gives you the proper result in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer therefore just updating it here.

You can get around the error by using INDEX and MATCH functions. Especially if it includes massive tables and multiple sheets.

I used the following to solve my issue and hope it helps others too.

`=INDEX('Users activity volumes'!A7:A367,MATCH('MH Users'!B8,'Users activity volumes'!B7:B367,0))`